Is a decentralised multisig possible with Polkadot?
As multisig validation with on-chain data only appears to be impossible, what approached would be advised to still make it decentralised?
Here's what I want to do:

A server initiates a call to a smart contract from a multisig account
Users member of that same multisig see in the mobile app we provide that a multisig tx requires their validation, which they can trigger from the app.

As on-chain data is insufficient to complete step 2, is a decentralised solution still possible without using a custom pallet (which would require us to develop our own parachain) ?

I am exploring this: https://github.com/use-ink/ink-examples/blob/main/multisig/lib.rs#L264
